# Get certain Feeds List history of Chat Room on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, filtering, rss

I have been trying to track a feed of when I was raised as an owner of a channel. So far no luck, went through chat history of 7 to 8 month's every single day.

Is there a way to get the list of feeds, the actions owner(s)/moderator of rooms took?

Retrieving such information may help us make our actions better by keeping track of history and having a knowledge of how power(s) are being used.

Like one in a image below:

[image: SOmeta369834 question example]

Comment: This works for SOCVR [`https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+of+this+room&user=-2&room=41570`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+of+this+room&user=-2&room=41570) so if you change the room number in that url, you might have some luck, unless the Feeds user got changed

Comment: @rene this helped. Thanks, but it only shows the adding room owner thing, not the other actions done by mods or room owners.  Plus, Why upvotes of this question is not gaining my repo? :o

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Votes are often used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of the Meta question. These votes won't affect your main site reputation.

Comment: You can scrape the transcript, but that is about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274146/158100 or as an alternative you can page through the [recent messages of a user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4993989/arr0w?tab=recent&page=10) but you have to build the page url yourself, the UI doesn't support paging.

Comment: @rene great and thanks for the knowledge!